# Drop partition if exists in HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I would like to know if there is a way to `DROP` a `partition` `IF EXISTS` in `HANA`.

I have tried like below

```
ALTER TABLE TBL_NAME DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION VALUE = '1234'
```

I am getting `incorrect syntax error near IF`

What is the best available solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HANA does not support the `IF EXISTS` clause.

You may want to work around this limitation by implementing your own "IF EXISTS", similar to what I presented here:
[If EXISTS would exist](https://www.lbreddemann.org/if-exists-would-exist/)